# How do I have my iPhone/iPad not ask for passcode for each iTunes backup?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, backup, password

iMac 2019 MacOS Mojave; iOS 15.7.1

Sometime after I updated my iPhone 8 and iPad (9th gen) I get a message on the iPhone/iPad every time I connect via USB to provide a passcode to back up the device.

"Enter passcode to Start a Backup"

On the iMac I get the following message about the passcode requirement with the choices Cancel or Try Again.

"iTunes could not back up the 'device' “device name” because it is locked with a passcode. You must enter your passcode on the 'device' before it can be backed up."

I believe the behavior started with iOS 15.7 for both devices.

I tried both settings for the "USB Accessories" preference under "Touch ID and Passcode" without success and I couldn't find any information about this change.

Any ideas how to turn off this persistent passcode prompting without disabling the passcode?

Edit: Devices *are* synced if Cancel is selected for prompts, just no backup.

Comment: Are you already unlocking the devices when you connect & this is then a secondary request?

Comment: This is a new "feature" of iOS.  You can't turn it off.

Comment: @MarcWilson - it's not 15.7.1, nor Mojave. I'm still on both these versions & no sign of this new behaviour. *Ah… 15.6.1… not 7. Will report back…*

Comment: 15.7.1 not available for phones capable of 16. Cannot test.

Comment: https://imazing.com/blog/imazing-216-ios16-ventura implies it wasn't happening before iOS 16, I don't have a device I can put 15.x on either.

Comment: Yes, devices are unlocked. 15.7.x is a security upgrade for non-16 users.

Comment: It's highly annoying to me as I had iMazing Mini backing up my phone every night automatically, and now that can't be done.

Comment: This is a total PITA. It isn’t so bad if you’ve connected via cable, but the wifi backups which just used to happen aren’t going to happen any more unless you notice your device asking for the passcode! Totally silly. The linked page in the previous answer says this affects iOS up to 15.7 and 16.0. My devices are all .1 past that, and are still doing it.

Comment: This is really a shame, me with my swiss-cheese brain rarely remembers to back up the phone regularly, and having iMazing Mini just **do** it when the Mac woke up to do its CCC backup was phenomenal.

Comment: iMazing has a complete analysis here as of 11/15: https://imazing.com/blog/ios-backup-passcode-prompt

Comment: I just filed a Feedback with apple about this and I'd encourage everyone else to do so as well; https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: JESUS this 'feature' is such a total annoyance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks to be a result of [CVE-2022-32929](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-32929).

From Apple's release note for [15.7](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213445) and for [16.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213489)...

> Backup
>
> Available for: iPhone 8 and later, iPad Pro (all models), iPad Air 3rd
> generation and later, iPad 5th generation and later, iPad mini 5th
> generation and later
>
> Impact: An app may be able to access iOS backups
>
> Description: A permissions issue was addressed with additional
> restrictions.
>
> CVE-2022-32929: Csaba Fitzl (@theevilbit) of Offensive Security

So... it's deliberate.  Maybe they'll back down, maybe they won't.

Edit... complete analysis [here](https://imazing.com/blog/ios-backup-passcode-prompt).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It is worse than that. It is yet another example of a request to enter my password. Teaches us to become blasé and enter password without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this new annoyance by telling iTunes DO NOT AUTO BACKUP during sync, I will do manual backups at my leisure thank you very much.

Follow this: https://www.technipages.com/disable-itunes-backup-process/

Comment: Please summarise the steps required into your answer rather than post a link. If the link goes dead then your answer is worthless.