# How do I stop macOS Ventura requiring a Passcode every time I Backup and Sync my iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, backup, ventura

I have a MacBook Air (M2). It came with Monterey installed

I have an iPhone 13 mini and two iPads - a 5th Gen iPad Air and an iPad mini 4.

They are all set up to backup and sync (over Wi-Fi) with my computer. This is deliberate, I do not want to backup all my devices to iCloud. My MacBook gets backed up in a number of ways including TimeMachine.

The devices used to backup and sync automatically and silently every time I plugged them in to charge overnight.

Since upgrading to macOS Ventura, every time the devices attempt to sync they require me to enter the device passcode.

I have also upgraded the phone to iOS 16 (when that came out, now 16.1) and the iPad Air to iPad 16 (once that was released, now 16.1).

The iPad mini is not eligible and so is still on iPadOS 15 (15.7.1). But it still asks for the passcode - so I am guessing it is a macOS thing and not an iOS/iPadOS thing.

How can I prevent the devices from requiring a passcode every time they attempt to sync?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449899/how-do-i-have-my-iphone-ipad-not-ask-for-passcode-for-each-itunes-backup [which has no answers as yet]

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Not a bug. As linked in a comment with the original question, this looks like intentional behaviour.

I believe this is a Mac OS Ventura bug as it's being reported by multiple people (see the link in the comments) and on other sites: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/the-trust-this-computer-password-prompt-shows-up-every-sync-on-ventura.2367279/

Issues include what you've posted and "trust this computer" being asked repeatedly.

Comment: It's not a bug.  See the question linked by @tetsujin.